# Как создать UWP проект под windows 10?

Tags: c#, uwp

Во время создания проекта в графе Целевая версия доступно только windows 11. После создания проекта в окне конструктора mainpage.xaml пишет: для отображения содержимого обновите среду до windows 11. Можно ли как то заигнорить блокировку простым способом или самое простое перейти на 11?

Comment: Давайте начнем с того что версия .NET какая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего что-то не установлено. На той же вкладке "Select the target ...", по всей видимости, отображаются установленные версии SDK, и ниже есть ссылка на [эту страницу](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version?ocid=VSClient_VerX_NewProject_version).

Для начала попробуй следовать этому руководству [Требуемые рабочие нагрузки и компоненты](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b#required-workloads-and-components).

Вот пример VS Installer - Отдельные компоненты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И да, пора перейти на Windows 11.